# How to write a job shop problem with these constraints in alpha|beta|gamma notation?

Tags: optimization, scheduling, notation

I have a job shop scheduling problem with the following characteristics. How would I write that in *alpha|beta|gamma* notation (see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_job_scheduling),[2](http://mat.uab.es/%7Ealseda/MasterOpt/79_03_scheduling_survey.pdf))? I know some of the parts, but not all. I add my suggestions in `code` blocks.

alpha:

- Job shop `J`
- number of machines is part of the input `m`

beta:

- batch processing `b` with job compatibilities `?` and capacity constraints `?` (i.e., a machine can process multiple jobs, if they belong to the same family and the machines capacity suffices. Each job has a fixed resource allocation which is the same on every machine.)
- release times `r_j`
- non-uniform setup times, depending on the schedule `?`
- transportation delays between machines, depending on the job and the machine `t_{j,k}`

gamma:

- minimizing total completion times `sum(C_j)`

Further: Is it true, that the job-shop implies a strict ordering of the jobs, so a precedence relation is implicit, or should i note that as well? In my problem, the jobs have to be processed by machines in the given order. (Btw.: The "direction" defines the compatibility.)

Example:

- Job 1: machines {1, 2, 3, 4}, comp. class A
- Job 2: machines {3, 4, 5}, comp. class A
- Job 3: machines {6, 5, 4, 3}, comp. class B

(Edit: Add links to sources about the notation.)

Comment: What is "alpha|beta|gamma" notation?  I've never heard of it.  Please provide a reference to a textbook or published paper that defines it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_job_scheduling

Comment: @WanderingLogic: from the wikipedia article, here is the link to the paper: http://mat.uab.es/~alseda/MasterOpt/79_03_scheduling_survey.pdf

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: thank you, that is what I mean.